# Write request.get response to json file in python

Tags: python, json

I am using requests.get in python for a URL to get the data as below:

```
import requests
username = 'ROAND'
password = dbutils.secrets.get("lab-secrets","ROSecret")
response = requests.get('https://pit.service.com/api/table', auth=(username,password))
```

The count for this is

```
print(response.headers)
X-Total-Count': '799434'
```

Im trying to load this into a json file as below:

```
data = response.content
with open('/path/file.json', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

But the file contains only 1439 records.

The json file content looks like the below image:

[image]

Ive tried multiple ways, but not successful.
I just want to exactly bring all my contents from requests.get into a json file.

Kindly help.

Comment: Instead of response.content, try response.json()

Comment: Hi Fred, I tried response.json() as you said. But getting error:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'

Comment: I'm guessing the API requires paging.  Check out the API docs,

Comment: @Roho If your intention is to write JSON then don't open the file in binary mode. Also, take a look at the *json* module and, in particular, the *dumps()* function

Comment: @Fred, I did try to remove the binary mode and keep only w, Also used the json.dump(data, f), still the same issue in all cases, only get a few records. out of 799434 I get only 1.5k records